# Raphael js text positioning: centering text in a circle

Tags: html, css, raphael, centering

I am using Raphael js to draw circled numbers. The problem is that each number has a different width/height so using one set of coordinates to center the text isn't working. The text displays differently between IE, FF, and safari. Is there a dynamic way to find the height/width of the number and center it accordingly?

Here is my test page:

http://jesserosenfield.com/fluid/test.html

and my code:

```
function drawcircle(div, text) { 
    var paper = Raphael(div, 26, 26); //<<
    var circle = paper.circle(13, 13, 10.5);
    circle.attr("stroke", "#f1f1f1");
    circle.attr("stroke-width", 2);
    var text = paper.text(12, 13, text); //<<
    text.attr({'font-size': 15, 'font-family': 'FranklinGothicFSCondensed-1, FranklinGothicFSCondensed-2'});
    text.attr("fill", "#f1f1f1");
}

window.onload = function () {
    drawcircle("c1", "1");
    drawcircle("c2", "2");
    drawcircle("c3", "3");
};
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 32):

(Answer rewritten): Raphael.js centers text nodes both horizontally and vertically by default.

"Centering" here means that the x, y argument of paper.text() method expects the center of the text's bounding box.

So, just specifying the same x, y value as the circle should produce the desired result:

```
var circle = paper.circle(13, 13, 10.5);
var text = paper.text(13, 13, "10");
```

[image: Example output]

([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ento/Uvzx3/))

Relevant source code:

- [source line responsible for vertical alignment](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/dbe241f4c5310dd9bf3b451c538d78c6c4a0e288/raphael.js#L1481)
- [source line responsible for horizontal alignment](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/dbe241f4c5310dd9bf3b451c538d78c6c4a0e288/raphael.js#L1751)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this:

```
var paper = Raphael(div, 26, 26); //<<
var circle = paper.circle(13, 13, 10.5);
circle.attr("stroke", "#f1f1f1");
circle.attr("stroke-width", 2);
var text = paper.text(0, 0, text); //<<
text.attr({'font-size': 15, 'font-family': 'FranklinGothicFSCondensed-1, FranklinGothicFSCondensed-2'});
text.attr("fill", "#f1f1f1");
text.translate((35 - text.getBBox().width)/2, (45 - text.getBBox().height)/2);
```

Comment: Output of this code looks better: text.translate(paper.width/2, paper.height/2);

Comment: `text.getBBox().width` doesn't work as it always returns 0 :(

Answer (score 3):

Use this attribute: `'text-anchor':'start'`:

```
paper.text( x, y, text ).attr( {'text-anchor':'start'} );
```

Comment: Thanks! This is so usefull. Had a lot of troubles aligning texts inside raphaels SVG, but thanks to this all my problems are gone! You rock :D

Answer (score 0):

The [Rotating Text Exactly](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php) example (listed in the right-hand column of the page, or [here in github](https://gist.github.com/265480)), discusses putting text in a precise position, along with, as usual, extra steps required to make things work in IE.

It does find a bounding box for the text; I imagine it is straightforward to move the text by half the bounding box as Jan suggested.